# Two sided reinforced "clamp" for creating a hole in screen

Tags: hose, screens

I have a pool with a large screened in enclosure. What I want to do, is create a small hole in one of the screens (toward or even flush with the bottom of the screen) where I can pass a hose or something through. Does there exist a product where I can attach a large surface area "clamp" of sorts (maybe one screws into the other) that will keep the tension in the screen, and then I can cut my hole in the middle of the flat clamps to pass a hose through?

I can imagine what I'm trying to accomplish, but was hoping there was some product out there already. I would expect the flat "clamps" to be about 4 square inches or more, with a hole in the middle -- and I would  cut the hole after the clamps are fastened to each other.

Comment: Of course, you could create it yourself from two pieces of polycarbonate sheet plastic. That said, screens tear easily, and if there is any tension or vibration on that pass-through, the screen won't last long.

Comment: add some rubber spline to the sandwich to distribute the tension.

Comment: Virtually any material you have on hand, screwed or riveted together, would do.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, look up "cat door for sliding screen door". These have a 2 flat frame pieces that snap together, suspended within the screen mesh itself. They also come with a lightweight swinging screen door that hangs from the frame.

If the cat door is too large for you, you could go down to the hardware store and have them make a tiny window screen frame. You would then use the frame spline channel and rubber spline to suspend the frame into your screen wall, cutting the screen fabric from the middle to make a hole. I would actually cut the sides and bottom of the fabric and let the flap hang to keep bugs out, maybe weighting it at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Curtain grommets (a kind brass eyelet) are available in suitable sizes. (I found 2"-12" in my first search.) You'll need to borrow or buy a setting tool to install them.

You'll need to cut the hole first (or during the install), so reinforce the hole perimeter with glue first.

Re-tensioning the mesh is fairly easy if you have a roller tool to set the rubber beading.

I've also seen factory-fitted doors in window screens to allow screens to be fitted inside "hinged" windows giving access to the window handle. I don't know if they can be retrofitted.

Answer (score 1):

This item looks to be a very close fit to what you are looking for.

[https://www.amazon.com/ScreenLet-Window-Screen-Through-Accessory/dp/B08N8M3S5G](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08N8M3S5G)

[image: ScreenLet window screen pass-through]

And here is one that is a bit larger. It is called a "screen wicket", so that might give you another term to search for.

https://www.swisco.com/Plastic-Screen-Wicket/pd/Replacement-Window-Operator-Accessories/56-090

[image: plastic screen wicket]

And "screen portal" might find some others that would fit your need, like this one:

https://www.bulkreefsupply.com/screen-top-feeding-portal-neat-aquatics.html

[image: screen portal]